# Detect yes/no answers using a pre-trained NLP model

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I'm making a chatbot where at the end of the process, it asks the user for confirmation, and the user would supposedly reply with yes/no-like responses ("Sure", "Why not?", "Nope", "Let's do it", ...etc).

I'm looking for a pre-trained model to do that for me as I don't want to train my own for various reasons.

Do you have any suggestions ? Is there a library of pre-trained models that I can browse for this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any pretrained model for that, but you could look on HuggingFace Hub. It should be easy to train a model like that using textcat in spaCy, for example.

Comment: I suspect there are no pretrained models for this use case because you can just ask the user to say "yes" or "no" explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [BERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BERT_(language_model))? This model was developed by Google and is probably the most popular pre-trained model for this task. TensorFlow Hub has several versions of BERT models available.

Comment: Do you have a link for a tutorial on how to achieve what I'm looking for please ? I looked by myself and only found bots that answer Yes/No, I'm looking for the inverse